# Entity Graph for nested associations of tables in Spring JPA

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, entitygraph

There are 3 tables in my db:

SalesOrderMaster
SalesOrderDetail
CustomerMaster

I have repository class SalesOrderDetailRespository.java which has this method findAll()

```
@EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"SalesOrderMaster"}, type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.FETCH)
List<SalesOrderInfo> findAll(@Nullable Specification<SalesOrderInfo> spec);
```

This is till now fetching the `SalesOrderMaster` record and associated `SalesOrderDetails` records. Now my requirement is in `SalesOrderInfo` class , I have added a new property for showing the Customer Information like Name , country which are there in CustomerMaster table.

The customerMaster table is related to SalesOrderMaster by customerId column. How do I add CustomerMaster table in the existing EntityGraph so that I can get this info?

Comment: You can specify an attribute path to that `attributePaths = {"SalesOrderMaster", "SalesOrderMaster.nameOfPropertyInSalesOrderMaster"}`

Comment: @DanielWosch , I tried. it is not working

Comment: But I understand you correctly that SalesOrderMaster contains a property representing the CustomerMaster?

Comment: @DanielWosch yes. Do I need to add that some where in the entity graph declaration?

Comment: Sure, that what I was talking about. Sorry :)
For example: `@EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"basket", "payment", "payment.history", "invoiceAddress"}, type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.LOAD) List<PurchaseOrderEntity> findAll()` => This fetches all `PurchesOrderEntites`with the named properties of the entity. PurchaseOrderEntity has a property called payment and payment has a property history => `payment.history` in entity graph

Comment: @DanielWosch I have in a similar way as you mentioned. Still it is not working. I have raised another question with the exact error message and how the named entity graph is defined. Can you please have a look at it : https://stackoverflow.com/q/67882006/8930751